# How to pass a SQL command statement as an argument to another function

Tags: python, sqlite

I am building a database application as practice. I want to use a set of functions to provide create, update, add, and delete functionality by constructing SQL commands which they will pass to a connector function that will handle the database connection, execute, commit, and close.

I have tried using "SQL command %s", (something)
Also tried the above but with ? instead of %s
This seems to be correct syntax, but is usually included directly into the execute function

```
import sqlite3

class Connector:

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.db_name = name
        self.table = "book"

    def change_table(self,table):
        self.table = table

    def create_db(self): 
        command = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, author TEXT, year INTEGER, isbn INTEGER)"
        return self.generic_connector(command)

    def insert(self,title,author,year,isbn):
        try:
            title = str(title)
            author = str(author)            
            isbn = int(isbn)
            year = int(year)
            command = "INSERT INTO book VALUES(:title,:author,:year,:isbn)", 
            {"title": title,"author": author,"year": year,"isbn":isbn} 
            print(command)
            return self.generic_connector(command)
        except ValueError:
            return 1

    def generic_connector(self,command):
        command = command[0], command[1]
        print(command)
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(self.db_name)
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute(command)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
            return rows
        except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
            print("oops")
```

When I print command, I expected to see :-

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, author TEXT, year INTEGER, isbn INTEGER)"
```

Instead, I got this :-

```
("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, author TEXT, year INTEGER, isbn INTEGER)", (self.table,))
```

Comment: How do u call the create_db method of the Connector class, it prints the table name as "book" when i do `connector = Connector('xyz')
connector.create_db()`

Comment: `execute` takes two arguments, not a tuple: `cur.execute(*command)`

Comment: Parameter substitution does not work for literals like table or column names.

Comment: @arajshree create_db doesn't take any parameters. Calling `Connector('xyz')` sets the database name as 'xyz'. I realize the function is a bit misleading, since `create_db` actually creates a table. The `__init__` method for Connector includes a default table name: 'book'